# setService(java.lang.Class<? extends com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService>) in Builder cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<T>)

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

## Description

I want to build notification app which app provide notification every 15 minutes.
Build this app i use FirebaseJobDispatcher job scheduler.But when i build my job using newJobBuilder().  but this time when i use setService() method then i got compile time error.I can not fix it. I have searched for an appropriate solution over the web but didn't find anything useful. Please help me.

## My Exception

```
setService
```

(java.lang.Class)
in Builder cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.Class)

## Photo

[image: Here is compile error photo]

## My WaterReminderFirebaseJobService Class

```
    package com.example.android.background.sync;

import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.RetryStrategy;

public class WaterReminderFirebaseJobService extends JobService {

    private AsyncTask mBackgroundTask;
    /**
     * The entry point to your Job. Implementations should offload work to another thread of
     * execution as soon as possible.
     *
     * This is called by the Job Dispatcher to tell us we should start our job. Keep in mind this
     * method is run on the application's main thread, so we need to offload work to a background
     * thread.
     *
     * @return whether there is more work remaining.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters jobParameters) {

        //  AsyncTask called mBackgroundTask.
        // Here's where we make an AsyncTask so that this is no longer on the main thread
        mBackgroundTask = new AsyncTask() {

            // COMPLETED (6) Override doInBackground
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                // COMPLETED (7) Use ReminderTasks to execute the new charging reminder task you made, use
                // this service as the context (WaterReminderFirebaseJobService.this) and return null
                // when finished.
                Context context = WaterReminderFirebaseJobService.this;
                ReminderTasks.executeTask(context, ReminderTasks.ACTION_CHARGING_REMINDER);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                // COMPLETED (8) Override onPostExecute and called jobFinished. Pass the job parameters
                // and false to jobFinished. This will inform the JobManager that your job is done
                // and that you do not want to reschedule the job.

                /*
                 * Once the AsyncTask is finished, the job is finished. To inform JobManager that
                 * you're done, you call jobFinished with the jobParamters that were passed to your
                 * job and a boolean representing whether the job needs to be rescheduled. This is
                 * usually if something didn't work and you want the job to try running again.
                 */

                jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
            }
        };

        mBackgroundTask.execute();
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Called when the scheduling engine has decided to interrupt the execution of a running job,
     * most likely because the runtime constraints associated with the job are no longer satisfied.
     *
     * @return whether the job should be retried
     * @see RetryStrategy
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        if (mBackgroundTask != null) mBackgroundTask.cancel(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

## My ReminderUtils Class

```
   /*
 * Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.example.android.background.sync;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Constraint;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Driver;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.FirebaseJobDispatcher;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayDriver;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Job;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Lifetime;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Trigger;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ReminderUtilities {
    private static final int REMINDER_INTERVAL_MINUTES=1;
    private static final int REMINDER_INTERVAL_SECONDS=(int)(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(REMINDER_INTERVAL_MINUTES));
    private static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME_SECONDS=REMINDER_INTERVAL_SECONDS;
    private static final String REMINDER_JOB_TAG="hydration_reminder_tag";
    private static boolean sInitialized;

    synchronized public static void scheduleChargingReminder(@NonNull final Context context){
        if(sInitialized) return;
        Driver driver=new GooglePlayDriver(context);
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher=new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);
        /* Create the Job to periodically create reminders to drink water */
        Job constraintReminderJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                /* The Service that will be used to write to preferences */
                .setService(WaterReminderFirebaseJobService.class)
                /*
                 * Set the UNIQUE tag used to identify this Job.
                 */
                .setTag(REMINDER_JOB_TAG)
                /*
                 * Network constraints on which this Job should run. In this app, we're using the
                 * device charging constraint so that the job only executes if the device is
                 * charging.
                 *
                 * In a normal app, it might be a good idea to include a preference for this,
                 * as different users may have different preferences on when you should be
                 * syncing your application's data.
                 */
                .setConstraints(Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING)
                /*
                 * setLifetime sets how long this job should persist. The options are to keep the
                 * Job "forever" or to have it die the next time the device boots up.
                 */
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                /*
                 * We want these reminders to continuously happen, so we tell this Job to recur.
                 */
                .setRecurring(true)
                /*
                 * We want the reminders to happen every 15 minutes or so. The first argument for
                 * Trigger class's static executionWindow method is the start of the time frame
                 * when the
                 * job should be performed. The second argument is the latest point in time at
                 * which the data should be synced. Please note that this end time is not
                 * guaranteed, but is more of a guideline for FirebaseJobDispatcher to go off of.
                 */
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(
                        REMINDER_INTERVAL_SECONDS,
                        REMINDER_INTERVAL_SECONDS + SYNC_FLEXTIME_SECONDS))
                /*
                 * If a Job with the tag with provided already exists, this new job will replace
                 * the old one.
                 */
                .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                /* Once the Job is ready, call the builder's build method to return the Job */
                .build();

        /* Schedule the Job with the dispatcher */
        dispatcher.schedule(constraintReminderJob);
        /* The job has been initialized */
        sInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The class is asking for a class that extends `com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService` and you are providing it a class that extends `android.app.job.JobService`

Comment: Thanks for comment.I got it.